# Timeout in blazor clientside application .net 8

Tags: .net, blazor, webassembly

we have a blazor client side application running .net 8.02.
localhost we can do long running httpsrequest with httpclient. we have added a timeout to the setup of httpclient. it works localhost.

however in production and staging environment it gets a timeout after 60 seconds no matter what we do.

The application is running in a webapp serving the files.

any suggestion to any setup we might have missed is highly appreciated.